# Not able to start embedded server for Kafka for Junit testing

Tags: junit, junit4, spring-kafka, spring-test

I am trying to workout already implemented example from github for understanding of Springboot Kafka unit testing through Junit.
I am new to testing.
I am using this code [Github](https://github.com/yildirimabdullah/spring-kafka-test/tree/master/src/main) 
When i try to run it as Junit then it gives me error mentioned below:

```
2021-06-16 18:14:15.907  INFO 9864 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
2021-06-16 18:14:15.918  INFO 9864 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-sender-1, groupId=sender] Revoke previously assigned partitions UpdatedBrandEvent-0, UpdatedBrandEvent-1
2021-06-16 18:14:15.918  INFO 9864 --- [           -C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : sender: partitions revoked: [UpdatedBrandEvent-0, UpdatedBrandEvent-1]
2021-06-16 18:14:15.918  INFO 9864 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-sender-1, groupId=sender] Member consumer-sender-1-95af1165-2ad8-4ea4-896b-28fbd9cef316 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:60727 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) due to the consumer unsubscribed from all topics
2021-06-16 18:14:15.920  INFO 9864 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-sender-1, groupId=sender] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2021-06-16 18:14:15.920  INFO 9864 --- [           -C-1] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService
2021-06-16 18:14:15.924  INFO 9864 --- [quest-handler-0] k.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator     : [GroupCoordinator 0]: Member[group.instance.id None, member.id consumer-sender-1-95af1165-2ad8-4ea4-896b-28fbd9cef316] in group sender has left, removing it from the group
2021-06-16 18:14:15.924  INFO 9864 --- [quest-handler-0] k.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator     : [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group sender in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-0) (reason: removing member consumer-sender-1-95af1165-2ad8-4ea4-896b-28fbd9cef316 on LeaveGroup)
2021-06-16 18:14:15.926  INFO 9864 --- [quest-handler-0] k.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator     : [GroupCoordinator 0]: Group sender with generation 2 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-0)
2021-06-16 18:14:15.936  INFO 9864 --- [           -C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : sender: Consumer stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:15.964  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.KafkaServer                 : [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:15.965  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.KafkaServer                 : [KafkaServer id=0] Starting controlled shutdown
2021-06-16 18:14:15.982  INFO 9864 --- [er-event-thread] kafka.controller.KafkaController         : [Controller id=0] Shutting down broker 0
2021-06-16 18:14:15.988  INFO 9864 --- [er-event-thread] state.change.logger                      : [Controller id=0 epoch=1] Sending UpdateMetadata request to brokers HashSet() for 0 partitions
2021-06-16 18:14:15.993  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.KafkaServer                 : [KafkaServer id=0] Controlled shutdown succeeded
2021-06-16 18:14:16.002  INFO 9864 --- [           main] icationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread : [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.003  INFO 9864 --- [-process-thread] icationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread : [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.003  INFO 9864 --- [           main] icationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread : [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.003  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.network.SocketServer               : [SocketServer brokerId=0] Stopping socket server request processors
2021-06-16 18:14:16.012  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.network.SocketServer               : [SocketServer brokerId=0] Stopped socket server request processors
2021-06-16 18:14:16.013  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandlerPool     : [data-plane Kafka Request Handler on Broker 0], shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.016  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandlerPool     : [data-plane Kafka Request Handler on Broker 0], shut down completely
2021-06-16 18:14:16.020  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-AlterAcls]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.220  INFO 9864 --- [per-0-AlterAcls] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-AlterAcls]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.220  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-AlterAcls]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.221  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.KafkaApis                   : [KafkaApi-0] Shutdown complete.
2021-06-16 18:14:16.222  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-topic]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.309  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-topic]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.309  INFO 9864 --- [nReaper-0-topic] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-topic]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.312  INFO 9864 --- [           main] k.c.transaction.TransactionCoordinator   : [TransactionCoordinator id=0] Shutting down.
2021-06-16 18:14:16.313  INFO 9864 --- [           main] k.c.transaction.ProducerIdManager        : [ProducerId Manager 0]: Shutdown complete: last producerId assigned 0
2021-06-16 18:14:16.314  INFO 9864 --- [           main] k.c.transaction.TransactionStateManager  : [Transaction State Manager 0]: Shutdown complete
2021-06-16 18:14:16.314  INFO 9864 --- [           main] k.c.t.TransactionMarkerChannelManager    : [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 0]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.318  INFO 9864 --- [rSenderThread-0] k.c.t.TransactionMarkerChannelManager    : [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 0]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.318  INFO 9864 --- [           main] k.c.t.TransactionMarkerChannelManager    : [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 0]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.319  INFO 9864 --- [           main] k.c.transaction.TransactionCoordinator   : [TransactionCoordinator id=0] Shutdown complete.
2021-06-16 18:14:16.320  INFO 9864 --- [           main] k.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator     : [GroupCoordinator 0]: Shutting down.
2021-06-16 18:14:16.321  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Heartbeat]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.510  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Heartbeat]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.510  INFO 9864 --- [per-0-Heartbeat] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Heartbeat]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.511  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Rebalance]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.544  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Rebalance]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.544  INFO 9864 --- [per-0-Rebalance] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Rebalance]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.545  INFO 9864 --- [           main] k.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator     : [GroupCoordinator 0]: Shutdown complete.
2021-06-16 18:14:16.545  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.ReplicaManager              : [ReplicaManager broker=0] Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.546  INFO 9864 --- [           main] k.s.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler  : [LogDirFailureHandler]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.546  INFO 9864 --- [rFailureHandler] k.s.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler  : [LogDirFailureHandler]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.546  INFO 9864 --- [           main] k.s.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler  : [LogDirFailureHandler]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.546  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager       : [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.548  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager       : [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.548  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager  : [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 0] shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.548  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager  : [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 0] shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.548  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.618  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.618  INFO 9864 --- [nReaper-0-Fetch] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.618  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Produce]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.726  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Produce]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.726  INFO 9864 --- [eaper-0-Produce] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Produce]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.726  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-DeleteRecords]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.744  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-DeleteRecords]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.744  INFO 9864 --- [0-DeleteRecords] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-DeleteRecords]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.744  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectLeader]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.945  INFO 9864 --- [r-0-ElectLeader] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectLeader]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.945  INFO 9864 --- [           main] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectLeader]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:16.956  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.ReplicaManager              : [ReplicaManager broker=0] Shut down completely
2021-06-16 18:14:16.957  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.log.LogManager                     : Shutting down.
2021-06-16 18:14:16.959  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.log.LogCleaner                     : Shutting down the log cleaner.
2021-06-16 18:14:16.960  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.log.LogCleaner                     : [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:16.961  INFO 9864 --- [leaner-thread-0] kafka.log.LogCleaner                     : [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:16.961  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.log.LogCleaner                     : [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:17.129  INFO 9864 --- [pool-8-thread-1] kafka.log.ProducerStateManager           : [ProducerStateManager partition=__consumer_offsets-0] Writing producer snapshot at offset 2
2021-06-16 18:14:17.280  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.log.LogManager                     : Shutdown complete.
2021-06-16 18:14:17.280  INFO 9864 --- [           main] rollerEventManager$ControllerEventThread : [ControllerEventThread controllerId=0] Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:17.281  INFO 9864 --- [           main] rollerEventManager$ControllerEventThread : [ControllerEventThread controllerId=0] Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:17.281  INFO 9864 --- [er-event-thread] rollerEventManager$ControllerEventThread : [ControllerEventThread controllerId=0] Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:17.285  INFO 9864 --- [           main] k.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine     : [PartitionStateMachine controllerId=0] Stopped partition state machine
2021-06-16 18:14:17.286  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.controller.ZkReplicaStateMachine   : [ReplicaStateMachine controllerId=0] Stopped replica state machine
2021-06-16 18:14:17.287  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.controller.RequestSendThread       : [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:17.287  INFO 9864 --- [r-0-send-thread] kafka.controller.RequestSendThread       : [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:17.287  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.controller.RequestSendThread       : [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:17.288  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.controller.KafkaController         : [Controller id=0] Resigned
2021-06-16 18:14:17.289  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient          : [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing.
2021-06-16 18:14:17.395  INFO 9864 --- [ain-EventThread] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : EventThread shut down for session: 0x1000683bf6a0000
2021-06-16 18:14:17.395  INFO 9864 --- [           main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper           : Session: 0x1000683bf6a0000 closed
2021-06-16 18:14:17.396  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient          : [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed.
2021-06-16 18:14:17.396  INFO 9864 --- [           main] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:17.447  INFO 9864 --- [           main] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:17.447  INFO 9864 --- [nelReaper-Fetch] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:17.447  INFO 9864 --- [           main] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:18.447  INFO 9864 --- [lReaper-Produce] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:18.447  INFO 9864 --- [           main] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:18.447  INFO 9864 --- [           main] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:18.453  INFO 9864 --- [           main] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:18.453  INFO 9864 --- [lReaper-Request] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Stopped
2021-06-16 18:14:18.454  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.network.SocketServer               : [SocketServer brokerId=0] Shutting down socket server
2021-06-16 18:14:18.482  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.network.SocketServer               : [SocketServer brokerId=0] Shutdown completed
2021-06-16 18:14:18.485  INFO 9864 --- [           main] kafka.server.KafkaServer                 : [KafkaServer id=0] shut down completed
2021-06-16 18:14:18.509  INFO 9864 --- [nnectionExpirer] o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory        : ConnnectionExpirerThread interrupted
2021-06-16 18:14:18.509  INFO 9864 --- [electorThread-1] o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory        : selector thread exitted run method
2021-06-16 18:14:18.509  INFO 9864 --- [ad:/127.0.0.1:0] o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory        : accept thread exitted run method
2021-06-16 18:14:18.510  INFO 9864 --- [electorThread-0] o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory        : selector thread exitted run method
2021-06-16 18:14:18.510  INFO 9864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:18.511  INFO 9864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.SessionTrackerImpl  : Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:18.511  INFO 9864 --- [           main] o.a.z.server.PrepRequestProcessor        : Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:18.511  INFO 9864 --- [           main] o.a.z.server.SyncRequestProcessor        : Shutting down
2021-06-16 18:14:18.511  INFO 9864 --- [0 cport:60719):] o.a.z.server.PrepRequestProcessor        : PrepRequestProcessor exited loop!
2021-06-16 18:14:18.511  INFO 9864 --- [   SyncThread:0] o.a.z.server.SyncRequestProcessor        : SyncRequestProcessor exited!
2021-06-16 18:14:18.511  INFO 9864 --- [           main] o.a.z.server.FinalRequestProcessor       : shutdown of request processor complete
2021-06-16 18:14:19.207  INFO 9864 --- [ SessionTracker] o.a.zookeeper.server.SessionTrackerImpl  : SessionTrackerImpl exited loop!
```

Please help me here as i am running this on my local.Do i need to modify any other configuration files in bin for that.

Comment: https://github.com/yildirimabdullah/spring-kafka-test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/springkafkatest/service/KafkaMessageProducerServiceIT.java

Comment: https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/how-to-integration-test-on-spring-kafka-producer-cb9d1caf0795

Comment: @GaryRussell this is the sample that he is referring, I think he is running the "application" instead of the test.

Comment: I don't see an error in that log; I had a different problem with the embedded zookeeper; that project is using an old, unsupported Boot version; see my answer for the changes I made to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That project is using an old, unsupported, version of Boot. I had problems with Zookeeper with that version on my Mac.

You are also missing `spring:` in the application.yml.

Here is what I did to get the test to pass.

Change the pom to use a supported Boot:

```
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
...
```

Fix the Yaml (main)

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
```

Fix the Yaml (test)

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
```

Fix the `KafkaProducerConfiguration`

```java
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;
```

[image]

If you used a boot-aware IDE (such as the Spring Tool Suite or IntelliJ you would have seen warnings about the bad YAML.